# R: Changing scale and format of axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to put together a graph of data points as a function of time elapsed over the date, but the problem is I have too many data points for the date string size as you can see in the graph below.

I'd prefer if I could have the X-Axis show just %Y-%m-%d instead of the full date and time, but I can't seem to get `scale_x_date`, `scale_x_datetime`, `xlim`, or `xmin` and `xmax` to work.

Errors I've gotten:

```
Error: Invalid input: time_trans works with objects of class POSIXct only
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

Code I have so far (with failures commented out):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

mydata <- read.csv("/Users/user/R/restore_graphs/CSV/store.csv.tmp")
restore.df = data.frame(
    Time = mydata$start,
    Duration = mydata$time,
    Labels = gsub(" [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}","",mydata$start)
)

p <- ggplot(restore.df, aes(x=Time,y=Duration)) + geom_point(colour="red") 

#p <- ggplot(restore.df, aes(x=Time,y=Duration)) + geom_point(colour="red") + scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d %H") 
#p + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%y-%m-%d", limits = as.Date('2018-06-14', "%y-%m-%d"), as.Date('2018-06-20', "%Y-%m-%d"))
#, xlim(as.Date('2018-06-14', "%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date('2018-06-20', "%Y-%m-%d")))) + geom_point(colour="red")# + xlim(as.Date('2018-06-14', "%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date('2018-06-20', "%Y-%m-%d")) 
#aes(xmin = as.Date("2018-06-14", "%Y-%m-%d"), xmax = as.Date("2018-06-20", "%y-%m-%d"))) #

dput(restore.df$Time)
print(p)
```

When I run the line with ggplot changed to:

```
p <- ggplot(restore.df, aes(x=Time,y=Duration,xmin = as.Date("2018-06-14", "%Y-%m-%d"), xmax = as.Date("2018-06-20", "%y-%m-%d"))) + geom_point(colour="red")
```

It changes the graph to have every point shoved to the left of the screen.

Sample data:

```
uuid,db,table,start,stop,time,size
941439639,test,,"2018-06-14 17:35:07","2018-06-14 17:35:07",62.9666666666667,141329782065
890252165,test,,"2018-06-14 23:35:38","2018-06-14 23:35:38",61.7166666666667,141380294237
943883747,test,,"2018-06-15 05:38:39","2018-06-15 05:38:39",77.7666666666667,141469254934
827384296,test,,"2018-06-15 11:35:11","2018-06-15 11:35:11",63.4166666666667,141276941916
454468935,test,,"2018-06-15 17:35:23","2018-06-15 17:35:23",64.4333333333333,141380122325
705894402,test,,"2018-06-15 23:35:29","2018-06-15 23:35:29",63.9,141715941073
396694772,test,,"2018-06-16 05:39:59","2018-06-16 05:39:59",75.0666666666667,141789270192
```

[image: Normal]

[image: With xmin and xmax]

Comment: You didn't convert the date-times to datetimes.  By default these are read as factors.  To convert you can do something like `Time = as.POSIXct(mydata$start)`.

Comment: That solved it perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)
ggplot(restore.df %>% 
       mutate(Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) %>% # here we convert to date type 
       filter(Time >= "2018-06-14", Time <= "2018-06-20"), # instead of defining xmin and xmax date ranges filter only dates you want to plot
               aes(x=Time, 
                   y=Duration)) + 
geom_point(colour="red") +
xlab("Date")
```

Comment: That got a lot closer than I did, however it grouped several items together when they shouldn't have been.

Comment: Updated the answer